# is there a way in excel (as opposed to vba) to use index match to return a value with a max function in the matching criteria?

Tags: excel, vba

i have a spreadsheet with many rows of data. i am trying to return a value from COL(C)-initials that matches the ID in COL(A) with the most recent timestamp in COL(B). the problem is that there are many ID matches but i only want to return the value from the one with the most recent timestamp in COL(B).

COL(A)-ID#
COL(B)-TIMESTAMP value
COL(C)-INITIALS

i have been trying variations of index, match but not sure how to work with the timestamp decision and the multiple matches/array issue. any help is appreciated. thank you.

the max function reference in the title was in reference to the most recent timestamp. i was thinking of using that if it would work, but not sure.

Answer (score 3):

Try

=INDEX(C2:C10,MATCH(MAX(IF(A2:A10=E1,B2:B10,0)),B2:B10,0))

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: thank you Teylyn. that worked perfect. i appreciate the help. the match 'if' was what i haven't seen before.

Comment: what do you do when the timestamp is a function? i don't think mine is working.

Comment: What do you mean with "timestamp is a function"? Whether or not the cell with the timestamp contains a function does not matter. The value of the cell is checked. If yours does not work, you may want to check the function that delivers your time stamp. What is it?

Comment: i wrote a function for the timestamp instead of using the now() fcn.

Comment: The only thing that matters if whether the cell contains a numeric value, so the maximum of the numbers can be calculated. What does your custom function return? Is that really a number?

Answer (score 1):

I would offer a word of caution with this. The formula provided above will work *as long as the times are unique*. If they weren't unique, checking the id range against the id to be returned would have to be performed a second time; once to get the maximum time value and a second time to make sure that only the time values associated with that id are considered for the match. Without the second check, only the *first* matching record can be reliably returned.

[image]

Standard formula with double-check:

`=INDEX($C$2:$C$99,MIN(INDEX(ROW($1:$98)+(($A$2:$A$99<>F$1)+($B$2:$B$99<>MAX(INDEX(($B$2:$B$99)*($A$2:$A$99=F$1),,))))*1E+99,,)))`

Array formula with double-check:

`=INDEX(C2:C10,MATCH(MAX(IF(A2:A10=F1,B2:B10,0)),B2:B10*(A2:A10=F1),0))`

The standard formula I provided has its cell ranges expanded down to row 99 to show that blank cells do not interfere with a correct result.

Comment: here is a screen shot of the rows and my formula for the timestamp. as you can see the index match should return 'sh' not 'mp'. on the other tab is where i have the formula

Comment: sorry. couldn't post image.

Comment: @user2578178 - Post the image to any public files sharing site and leave a link to the image back here or edit your original question and add some sample data. If you preface all lines of data with 4 spaces, they will enn up formatted properly. The latter is preferred as I won't have to retype the sample data.

Comment: @user2578178 - I strongly suspect that you mistyped the `ROW(1:98)` in your effort to transcribe the standard formula for your own purposes. `ROW(1:98)` is the *position within* `$C$2:$C$99`, not the actual row on the worksheet. This is a common mistake. e.g. if your actual data was `$C$25:$C$110` then you would use `ROW($1:$86)`.

Comment: @jeeped, if the time stamp contains seconds, not just hour and minute, the likelihood that the same ID has duplicate time stamps may be acceptable. Really depends on the situation. If the table receives ten new entries a day, there should not be a problem. If we are looking at hundreds of entries per minute, a different approach than the one I posted is certainly required.

Comment: @teylyn - Your solution more than adequately covered the OP's requirement. I only offered this 'word of caution' to your accepted answer for the benefit of future viewers whose own requirements may be more critical than the sorted and unique data provided by the OP of this thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `Index-Match` or `Vlookup` in this case, just ensure your data is sorted by timestamp in descending order.  The function returns the first match it finds.  I suspect an array formula will also work, but will likely perform more slowly than doing it this way.

[image]

Comment: thank you for the response, however i used the index-match like Teylyn suggested. my timestamp column is the result of a formula and i suspect that is stopping the search on the first one it comes to... and i can't ensure that the data is sorted. large spreadsheet for a customer that can only use basic tools like excel.

Comment: I'm glad the previous answer works! And I'm not sure why you can't sort the data as that is trivial in Excel.

Comment: i can sort the data. however, it is not practical for the users of the end product. thanks.

Comment: Haha, if your end users can't figure out how to sort data in Excel, I'm not sure they can figure out how to put in a matrix formula.  In any case, good luck anyway.

Comment: @rmayer06 I think you are missing a big part of the picture and your "haha"-ing only highlights that ignorance. The asker is designing a spreadsheet that will be used by people who have only basic Excel skills.  They will never need to enter an array formula (not a "matrix" formula, by the way. You may want to learn the proper terms if you throw them around).

Comment: Seriously folks. I presented a very simple answer, and unless I am incorrect in my answer (and I don't believe I am), it is the easiest solution. There appears to be discussion and confusion on the other answers. If the user can't figure out how to sort data (an extremely basic spreadsheet function) then there is no help for them. End of discussion. I am sorry if I sound flippant.

Comment: yes. you are incorrect. Teylyn is right. you sound flippant. i don't need the users to 'have to figure it out'..

Comment: I still see value in leaving the answer up, as there are those who may find it useful, even if you don't.